# Why is `DispatchResultWithPostInfo` expected?

Tags: pallet, frame

The compiler: expected `DispatchResultWithPostInfo`

It found:  `) -> DispatchResult {`

I want to use `DispatchResult` and do not understand what the problem is.

Additional context:

```
#[frame_support::pallet]
pub mod pallet {
    use super::*;

    ...

    #[pallet::call]
    impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {
        #[pallet::weight(10_000)]
        pub fn foo(
            origin: OriginFor<T>
        ) -> DispatchResult {
            Ok(())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share more of the code, for example your return statement?

Comment: Return is `Ok(())`. The function does nothing else.

Comment: Can you share the whole extrinsic then? I wouldn't expect a problem here either given the information you have shared so far.

Comment: Added some more code.

Comment: It is part of a project that was using FRAME v1 but I have updated this particular pallet to use v2 attribute macros. Could this be relevant?

Comment: Its hard do say, I am not sure the problem here. If you did this in a brand new project on the latest version of Substrate, you would not have this issue. The best solution is probably to just listen to the compiler and return `Ok(().into())`

Comment: Could be that you are just using an older version of Substrate here. I think at one point, we didn't have logic in the macros to support both return types.

Answer (score 1):

As Shawn mentions in a comment, you are likely using an older version of Substrate where only `DispatchResultWithPostInfo` was supported. In newer versions both `DispatchResultWithPostInfo` and `DispatchResult` are supported as extrinsic return types. A workaround should be to change `Ok(())` to `Ok(().into())`.